# Async jobs cancellation causes parent cancellation

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I tried to run two async jobs.

There is a button when clicked, would cancel one of the jobs. But I noticed when I do it, the other job will be cancelled too.

What happened?

```
class SplashFragment : BaseFragment(R.layout.fragment_splash), CoroutineScope by MainScope() {

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    launch {
        val countdown = async { countDown() }
        val ipAndMaintain = async { checkIPAndMaintain() }

        btnSkip.onClick {
            countdown.cancel() // cancel countdown
            btnSkip.isVisible = false
            if (!ipAndMaintain.isCompleted) {
                showLoadingDialog()
            }
        }
        countdown.await()
        startOtherPage(ipAndMaintain.await())
    }
}

private suspend fun countDown() {
    var time = 3
    while (time >= 0) {
        btnSkip.text = getString(R.string.skip, time)
        delay(1000)
        yield()
        time--
    }
}

private suspend fun checkIPAndMaintain(): Int {
    delay(2000)
    return 1
}
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `await` on a cancelled `Deferred` it throws an Exception. If you don't catch it then it will be propagated to the parent coroutine which will cancel all its children. Wrap your `countdown.await()` instruction with a `try-catch` block and you'll see that the other coroutine continues. That's the effect of structured concurrency.

You can read [this article](https://medium.com/@elizarov/structured-concurrency-722d765aa952) by [Roman Elizarov](https://medium.com/@elizarov) about the topic.

Comment: Another effect of structured concurrency is that, if `async { countDown() }` fails, it will also cause the parent and all its children to be cancelled, whether or not you catch the exception from `await()`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Got it. Thanks.